# How do i Create "Slide-Out Navigation Panel" with Non movable(Fixed) UINavigation Bar in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, menu, uinavigationcontroller, slide

In one of my app i want to create Side left menu as many popular app provide.
I have already done it my projects using [PPRevealSideViewController](https://github.com/ipup/PPRevealSideViewController).

But the issue is it is not supported with Non movable UINavigation bar.

It only supported with Below UI.

[image: Supported UI]

Whereas Below is My requirement.

[image: Required UI]

**Requiremt is:** Top UInavigationBar must be Non movable and fixed and another ViewController slide the FirstView Controller.

I tried to hack with the library But till now not able to reach to my requirement.

Does any of you have done similar thing? Or any suggestions?

Any Help will be appreciated.

Thanks  & Regards,

Jenifer.

Comment: This might help you https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=&q=navigation+drawer

Comment: First of all, kudos for a beautiful app! Second, it looks like you're using view controller containment to achieve your first solution. Have you thought about having the navigation drawer just be a `UIView` that pushes or overlaps the `UIView` (or perhaps a container `UIView`) in your `UIViewController`? I think that's the way you'll have to go; I don't **think** you can push a `UIViewController` and not push its `UINavigationBar`.

Comment: @mbm29414, By Sliding UIView I need to add it in all my UIViewControllers where i need top attach this Slider View!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find Demo of similar 3rd party Library named as [CCKFNavDrawer](https://github.com/calvinchankf/CCKFNavDrawer).

You need to do some settings with this as below:

1. In `CCKFNavDrawer.m` class add below code once in `viewDidLoad:` method

   `self.shawdowView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];`

   and comment else where ,
2. set ContentInset as Below:

   `[self.drawerView.drawerTableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];`
3. Change Below stuff:

   `self.outFrame = CGRectMake(-self.menuWidth,64,self.menuWidth,self.meunHeight);
    self.inFrame = CGRectMake (0,64,self.menuWidth,self.meunHeight);`

Tell me if you need more help regarding this.